# Form is at the smallest size

Tags: css, html, forms

The title might be a little vague, but it's the best explanation of my problem. I messed something up in my CSS code which currently keeps my form at a weird size where width is somewhere near 0.

I added a picture to show what it looks like:

[image: This is the problem]

I tried adding `width: 100px;` to my CSS file, but it didn't do anything. Here is the CSS and HTML code:

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
select,
textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px #dbdbdb;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 100px;
}

input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
select {
    height: 2.75em;
    width: 100px;
}

textarea {
    padding: 0.75em 1em;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    resize: vertical;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION["username"]) and $_SESSION["username"] == "No User")
    {
        echo"<form action='index.php' method='post'>
        <input type= 'text' name='gebruikersid' placeholder='Gebruikersnaam' size='20' maxlength='20' required>
        <input type= 'email' name='mail' placeholder='Email Addres' size='20' maxlength='50' required>
        <input type= 'password' name='wachtwoord' placeholder='Wachtwoord' size='20' maxlength='30' required>
        <input type= 'password' name='wachtwoordcheck' placeholder='Wachtwoord bevestigen' size='20' maxlength='30' required>
        <input type= 'text' name='voornaam' placeholder='Voornaam' size='20' maxlength='30' required>
        <input type= 'text' name='achternaam' placeholder='Achternaam' size='20' maxlength='30' required>
        <select name='sekse'>
            <option value='Man'>Man</option>
            <option value='Vrouw'>Vrouw</option>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' name='reg' value='Registreer'>

        </form>";
    }
?>
```

For some reason when I run this from Stack Overflow it looks like it's supposed to look. Does that mean there is nothing wrong with this part of the code? Because in that case I'll have to go look at other parts, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code seems to be absolutely correct. Check the inherited styles. You can find it easily in Chrome Dev Tools. In the [CSS toolbar](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference) you can find the full list of selectors and properties that affect each particular element.

From the picture it looks like somewhere red outline is passed. Try to find this selector out (if it's not debugging).

Comment: somehow my pc isn't updating the page when I make changes to the css file so I'm currently using my phone to see the changes and that seems to work

Comment: I suggest you to hardly refresh the page with clearing cache (using a `Ctrl+Shift+R` on Windows and Linux or `Cmd+Shift+R` on MacOS). It often is really helpful.

Comment: Also, it might be possible that you have an extension that overrides styles on desktop. To check it open the page in the anonymous tab or in another browser.

Comment: Thank you for the tip will do that. as for the extensions I use none so that shouldn't be the problem but I'll try it anyway

Answer (score 0):

For some reason changes to my CSS file don't show up on my pc. I went to my phone and the changes were applied. Changing the width worked, but just not on my pc. Very weird. It is probably a drawback of my school server.

Anyway, the code is actually working just not showing up directly on my pc.

If anyone else has this issue you just simply use:
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to clear the cache and afterwards the edits in the .css file should be added.